# Open emoji panel from code in uwp app

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Windows allows user to open emoti panel by pressing `win` + `.` in any textbox.
I was wondering if there is a way I can open it by calling some method.

[image: emoti panel]

Comment: You can try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de85d3d3-d9cd-456d-84b1-582344e96fc0/creating-emoji-layout-in-windows-10-uwp-app?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: @TheTanic I checked your post, what you are doing is customizing control template, I want to utilize core windows features to give a native look

Comment: If the answer answers your question feel free to accept it

Answer (score 6):

You can call the following. Thanks @RaymondChen for the info.

```
CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().TryShow(CoreInputViewKind.Emoji);
```

Comment: This is dependent upon implementation detail. (Maybe the hotkey changes to something else in the future.) It also requires a very dangerous capability (input injection). Better is to just call `CoreInputView.TryShow(CoreInputViewKind.Emoji)`.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen. Any example of how it could be used in UWP app would be appreceiated. :)

Comment: `CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().TryShow(CoreInputViewKind.Emoji);`

Comment: Cheers! You are the missing link :) A better way to manage is, as you've suggested. I wasn't aware of how to call it. So thanks! You've helped me out too. Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: Please update your answer with the improved solution so that others looking for the same thing will see the best answer first.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18247102-emoji-control) and the [linked ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/944) on the UWP-Toolkit GitHub, is there no native emoji panel/dialog. So you need to implement it by yourself or use a thirdparty library.

For an own implementation you can take a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de85d3d3-d9cd-456d-84b1-582344e96fc0/creating-emoji-layout-in-windows-10-uwp-app?forum=wpdevelop).